# Redirecting amp url to non amp url

Tags: redirect, htaccess

My wordpress use custom permalinks url with rules `/%postname%.html`

And Htaccess rules

```
# This file was updated by Duplicator Pro on 2021-11-02 05:53:04.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So my post url looks like this (with amp plugin)

`https://www.host.com/post.html` <--- original url

`https://www.host.com/post.html/amp` <--- amp url

`https://wwww.host.com/post.html/amp/` <--- amp url

`https://wwww.host.com/post.html?amp`  <--- amp url

`https://wwww.host.com/post.html?amp=1` <--- amp url

I have disabled amp plugin recently , this leave me with thousand not found url from previous amp url ..and i used solution provided on this answer   `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733666/htaccess-to-remove-amp-from-the-end-of-a-url/46231142`

so my htaccess looks like this

```
# This file was updated by Duplicator Pro on 2021-11-02 05:53:04.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But then i moved from shared hosting to vps (centos 7) ..using the same rules, now it add additional slash in url `https://www.host.com/post.html/` where it should be `https://www.host.com/post.html`

```
Request 
> GET /post.html/amp/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.host.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246
Response 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 07:43:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Content-Length: 274
< Connection: keep-alive
< location: https://www.host.com/post.html/
< cache-control: max-age=0
< expires: Thu, 04 Nov 2021 07:43:16 GMT
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Server: cloudflare
```

my apology if i post to long question, but i need help to redirect `/amp` `/amp/` `?amp` `?amp=1` `?amp=0` to original non amp url

Thank you

Comment: This question would be better asked on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as it doesn't really have anything to do with WordPress development.

Comment: You've introduced a `wwww` subdomain in your 3rd, 4th and 5th example URLs - in this a typo? Although if it is a typo then your 2nd and 3rd example URLs are the same - should one perhaps be missing the trailing slash?

Comment: "But then i moved from shared hosting to vps" - Are you implying this all worked as intended at the shared host?

Comment: ah yes there's typo on 3rd and 4th url my bad , and regarding migration, no and yes ...htaccess rule above doesn't works on `?amp` , its only works on `/amp/`  but i've installed plugin to handle `?amp`